# Выборка событий из БД по временной метке

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sqlite3

У меня есть база данных Sqlite3, в таблице `report` имеется поле `date INTEGER`, в нем хранятся временные метки `unix timestamp`, я хочу сделать две выборки:

1.Все записи за предыдущий месяц;

2.Все записи с первого числа текущего месяца по сегодняшний день.

Но к сожалению, не могу понять как работать с `timestamp`, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно делать такие запросы?

Answer (score 0):

берете нужную вам дату, приводите ее к строке unix

Например получить текущее время в формате unix:

```
strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime')
```

преобразовать 2019-01-01 00:00:01 в unix формат:

```
strftime('%s','2019-01-01 00:00:01')
```

если у вас поле в формате INTEGER то полученную строку надо привести к INTEGER для сравнения

```
CAST(strftime('%s','2019-01-01 00:00:01') as integer)
```

пример запроса

```
select * from report r 
where r.date BETWEEN CAST(strftime('%s','2019-01-01 00:00:01') as integer) AND CAST(strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime') as integer)
```